# How to invalidate or destroy jwt default token as external bearer in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, jwt

I am using web api and implemented default behavior for login i.e. endpoints using jwt authentication and now I am facing issue in invalidating or destroying jwt token as I want to implement logout functionality.
Can anyone suggest the logic for this situation how to deal with JWT tokens expiration?
Note: For login GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method is used as usual and it creates the token for authentication purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have issued your token it will be active until it expires.

If you need to perform a logout or 'invalidate' the token you will need to perform an extra step.

What you could do is store a SessionId (that is a guid) in the db on the User table. When a user logs in send the session id alongside the beader token. Store this session id in a cookie or in sessionStorage or whatever and send it up to the server with each request. Then you can have a filter applied globally to every action that checks the SessionId sent up from the client matches the SessionId stored in the database.

Then if you need to invalidate the token then store a new guid SessionId in the user table, when the next request comes it won't match and you can return a 401 response.

Comment: That would mean one user can only be logged in on one device? If I logout on my tablet, my desktop will have lost it's token as well.

Comment: that's correct, you could have a list of session Ids in that case. And you would then remove the session id from the list to invalidate it

Comment: thnx for the answer @MattjeS but I know this can be done as extra step as we all are doing the same way for authentication in traditional approach. But then we should opt for traditional approach only, as we need an extra work even after using JWT because we can manage custom tokens too by ourself. What is the need for using JWT and managing token ourself too?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invalidate certain tokens, you need to store the tokens you give out in a database.

Then you check against those tokens when you validate the incoming token.

When you need to invalidate one, just delete it from the database.

Comment: and how do you do it apart from that it is the same as storing passwords in plain text